# Getting error while installing Tailwind CSS in React App

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I am installing Tailwind CSS and getting below error while running 'npx tailwindcss init -p' and getting below error:

```
PS C:\Users\DELL\OneDrive\Documents\MERN\share&care\sharecare\frontend> npx tailwindcss init -p
'care\sharecare\frontend\node_modules\.bin\' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\DELL\OneDrive\Documents\MERN\tailwindcss\lib\cli.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```